# Managed Package: Updating Connected App callback url on packaging org after release

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps

We've released major version of our package with connected app in it and callback url pointing to our production heroku application.

And now we are going to start working on the next version of our package and during development process we would need to create couple of beta versions of our managed package to test changes etc. And we need to update callback of our connected app to point to QA version of heroku application in order not to mess up with production service.

The question here is: if updated connected app callback url on packaging org and released beta version, would it impact in anyway our clients on latest major version released previously? In other words, would our connected app in previously released major version be still sending request to prod heroku application, or would it be switched to qa right away?

It's more of a question like whether packaged connected app is more like a singleton owned by packaging org, or do we have a separate isolated connected apps per each major version released? Since consumer and secret keys are always staying the same, I would assume that it's one global instance shared by all package version (betas and majors), thus update in url callback would break existent integration on clients org right away.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is documented in the standard is guide

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm

As per the document the behavior is until you upgrade the package in subscriber org , the previous version of connected app is applied if connected app is a part of managed package .

In other words salesforce does version connected apps in managed package and it won't break others when you do a BETA version or next version.

I suggest you do a quick proof of concept in another developer environment to be double sure of what is there in docs.

Comment: The docs are very vague about this. From what we've tested, it's right the opposite case, i.e. just updating callback url on packaging org (even without releasing a beta version) makes existent integration on subscriber orgs fail with an error like 'callback url does not match'. Another interesting use case we've tested - you can create new connected app in a packaging org (without even including it in a package itself), and then you can configure existent subscribers with this app keys and integration just works. Seems like packaging org hosts/owns connected app, but not a package version.

Comment: The second behavior I am familiar but first one to me is bit weird one .I suggest you raise a case so Salesforce is aware of it and documents it in better terms .